# A specific word for stating something so obvious it is not useful to state

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

For example, answering the question "what is this?" with an overly literal response.The word I am trying to remember would be used in the phrase "Not to be XXX but unexpected events are unexpected. That's why we didn't expect it." (The word isn't 'tautological' or 'redundant')

Comment: could it be "blunt"?

Comment: See http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/257591/english-equivalent-to-spanish-idom-to-discover-america-the-mediterranean/257610#257610

Comment: See http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/11087/word-for-stating-the-obvious?rq=1

Comment: I liked Captain Obvious on that page.  Hope I remember it when there is an occasion for it.

Comment: If it amounts to restating essentially the same thing in a different way, or with different words - then it is a *tautology*.

Comment: It's not a single word, but a common phrase is _it goes without saying that..._

Comment: "Not to be **the obvious troll (who is obvious)**, but unexpected events are unexpected."

Answer (score 2):

I might go with ***trivial***, which means "simple, transparent, or immediately evident" (sense 4b, [here](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/trivial)).

- "Not to be trivial, but unexpected events, are, well, unexpected."

But I don't think this captures your case of answering "What is this?" with an overly literal response.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest **[axiomatic](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/axiomatic?s=t)**:

> self-evident; obvious

Answer (score 0):

Vacuous: "having or showing a lack of thought or intelligence; mindless."

Your statement, "unexpected events are unexpected" might be called *vacuously true* if in a mathematics context.

Comment: It also has the sense of completely devoid of content, which I think is what is being asked for.

Answer (score 0):

An overly literal response would be 'pedantic'.